# Excel VBA - Copy data after autofiltering starting with column B

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I_m trying to filter datas in a sheet with the autofilter and copy the results to another sheet. This works so far but I need the data starting with column B. I haven't found a solution so far. Hope someone can help me :)

```
    Dim myRange As Range

lZeile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lZeile



ActiveSheet.Rows("7:7").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="x"

On Error Resume Next
Set myRange = Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(lZeile, 19)).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If myRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "no cells"
Else
    Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange, Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Offset(7)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

Comment: Add a column offset and resize or you could just copy the whole lot and then delete the first column.

Comment: Is there anything in Column A before you apply the filter?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should give you your desired result - based on the headers for your data-to-copy being in row 7 of sheet 1.  Let me know how it goes.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyFilterX()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim CheckRow As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws1.Cells(7, 1).CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 12, "x"
    CheckRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        If CheckRow = 7 Then
            MsgBox "no cells"
            .AutoFilter
            Exit Sub
        End If
    .Offset(1, 1).Copy ws2.Cells(1, 1)
    .AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
Set myRange = Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(lZeile, 19)).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
```

with this one:

```
Set myRange = Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(lZeile, 19)).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
```